# I want to add animation to bell icon in my app toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

I want to link my android app to the webpage. whenever the content of the web page changes a trigger should be fired and create animation to the bell icon in toolbar of my android app, so that user is able to know there is something new added to the webpage. please help!!

Comment: I think help this link https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

**Create animation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="80"
    android:fromDegrees="-10"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="10" />
```

**Create menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_notification"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_layout"
        android:title="Notification"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Create custom layout for menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivNotification"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_notification"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Add animation code in activity**

```
public class Testactivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ImageView ivNotification;
    Animation shake;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Shake");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shake();
            }
        });
        shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        setContentView(btn);
    }

    private void shake() {
        ivNotification.startAnimation(shake);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ivNotification = (ImageView) menu.findItem(R.id.item_notification).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.ivNotification);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```